# When should an Action reside in the Default Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

From a design standpoint, if I want my site to have two URLs like the following -

www.mysite.com

and

www.mysite.com/Stuff

If my Default controller is `HomeController`, when should the "Stuff" action be in the `HomeController`?

When should the "Stuff" action *not* be in the `HomeController`?

Also, *how* do I not have the "Stuff" action reside in the `HomeController`, and still appear like the following - www.mysite.com/Stuff?
Would this be bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last question the simple solution would be to have `StuffController` created and then have and `indexAction` in this controller which will be the one executed when going to the url www.mysite.com/Stuff.

Now regarding when one should create a controller or just add an action to an existing controller you have to know what you want to do. Think of controller as containers of functionality of your application. If you need is to have a certain functionality that requires many different responses for various requests you should create a controller and add action for the various requests.

If you need to serve just on response then you should add an action to the appropriate container (Controller).

Do not mix controllers and actions to what URLs look like. You can manipulate this through routes.

```
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is subjective.  Without modifying your routes, you would need to create a `StuffController` with an action of `Index` to get that URL to resolve.  So I would say one downside to creating a `Stuff` action on the `HomeController` is that you need to modify the default routes to behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

www.mysite.com/Stuff doesn't point to an action method. It looks for a controller named `StuffController` with `Index` action. It all depends the routes you define in your `global.asax` file.

add the following route to put the action in HomeController

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Stuff",
                url: "Stuff/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Stuff", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

To put Stuff action in different controller use this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Stuff",
                url: "Stuff/{id}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Your Controller", action = "Stuff", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

EDIT: To answer your other question about design, I think it is a bad design practice to have action in one controller and url with another controller because you might as well place the action method in the controller you want as url. According to me it doesn't make sense. Although sometimes it may depend on the business.